# LDBC-SNBStorage Error: Not the leader of xx. Please retry later

Tags: nebula-graph

I'm using the data from LDBC SNB sf100, with 280 million nodes and 1.8 billion edges.
According to nebula-bench, I used nebula-import to complete the data import.

When executing nGQL statement, it indicated `Storage Error: Not the leader of xx. Please retry later` and may succeed after several attempts.

```
MATCH (root:Person)-[:KNOWS*1..2]-(friend:Person) \
WHERE id(root)==21990232978350 and friend <> root \
WITH collect(distinct friend) as friends \
UNWIND friends as friend \
    MATCH (friend)<-[:HAS_CREATOR]-(message) \
    WHERE coalesce(message.`Comment`.creationDate,message.Post.creationDate) < datetime(timestamp(1324080000)) \
RETURN \
    id(friend) AS personId, \
    friend.Person.firstName AS personFirstName, \
    friend.Person.lastName AS personLastName, \
    id(message) AS commentOrPostId, \
    coalesce(message.`Comment`.content,message.Post.content,message.Post.imageFile) AS commentOrPostContent, \
    timestamp(coalesce(message.`Comment`.creationDate,message.Post.creationDate)) AS commentOrPostCreationDate \
ORDER BY \
    commentOrPostCreationDate DESC, \
    commentOrPostId ASC \
LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, one storage service, or storaged, is out of memory, when you see this error message:Storage Error: Not the leader of xx. Please retry later